# When should I use ObjectId vs UUID in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm making a simple CRUD application with MongoDB so I can learn more about it.

The application is a simple blog, I have a collection named "articles" which stores various documents, each one representing a post for my blog.

When I display the list of all blog posts, I can do a db.collection.find(), and list all of them.

But the question lies when I need to show a single post individually, when I need to query the collection for a single, specific document.

The logical solution would be to use a RDBMS and an auto increment feature, but MongoDB is NoSQL and does not have auto increment.

I'm using the auto generated _id field of the document which stores an ObjectId by default, which means that my url's look like this:

```
http://localhost/blog/article.php?_id=5d41f6e5fc1a2f3d80645185
```

I saw in the documentation that the ObjectId contains a unique identifier for the server, together with a timestamp and a counter, isn't exposing these things a security risk?

As a solution, I stumbled into UUID https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID/ which is an auto-generated unique ID, that doesn't expose timestamp and machine info in it. It seems like a logical solution to use this instead of the _id that contains my ObjectId for querying and finding a document.

So I can make my url's look like this:

```
http://localhost/blog/article.php?_id=23829651-26f7-4092-99d0-5be8658c966e
```

But still, should I keep the _id property? should I add another one called "id" that stores the UUID? should I even use UUID's at all?

Comment: A different option would be to create stubs from the title. The first X number of characters, strip everything but spaces and letters, and replace spaces with dashes. Instead of `http://localhost/blog/article.php?_id=5d41f6e5fc1a2f3d80645185` you could get `http://localhost/blog/article.php?post=how-i-learned-to-draw`; or if you handled 404s with a custom error pages that checks the database to see if the post exists, you could have `http://localhost/blog/how-i-learned-to-draw`

Comment: Additionally, it's just an identifier for your machine and is not inherently very sensitive data, just unique and really only [theoretically a vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4588089/1843510). UUID is more appealing, but long - it certainly exposes zero information about your systems however.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would consider before choosing an identifier:

#### Collision

Risk of collision is very low for both `UUIDs` and `ObjectIDs`. This has been discussed in detail in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606364/collision-probability-of-objectid-vs-uuid-in-a-large-distributed-system).

#### Nature

`UUIDs` are random whereas `ObjectID` values always increase over time. This makes `ObjectIDs` a bad choice for [sharding](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#std-label-sharding-shard-key-selection).

#### Other uses

`ObjectIDs` have the creation timestamp as a part and can be used as a substitute of commonly used the `createdAt` field. A sort by `ObjectIDs` is a sort by creation time.

#### Insecure object references (OWASP)

Short def: An attacker cannot deduce the ID of another object if they have the ID of one object. You can read more about this [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). Both `UUIDs` and `ObjectIDs` are not vulnerable to this.
Link to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587523/mongodb-is-it-safe-to-use-documents-id-in-public/4588089#4588089) that discusses the security of `ObjectIDs` (thanks zbee).

#### Ease of use

**Note: This is subjective**
Using `ObjectIds` is a lot easier in the Mongo ecosystem. The existence of speical aggregation operators to deal with `ObjectIDs` + libraries add to it.

#### Portability

`UUIDs` are more portable than `ObjectIDs`. I do not know of any other system that uses `ObjectIDs` internally except for Mongo. Whereas there are other DBs such as Postgres that have a special data type for `UUIDs` + extensions for random generation etc.