# Is it dangerous to expose MongoDB's _id to the frontend?

Tags: mongodb

In general, is it dangerous to expose MongoDB's _id to the frontend (e.g. websites / mobile apps)? Would there be any security concerns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: is it safe to use document's ID "in public"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587523/mongodb-is-it-safe-to-use-documents-id-in-public)

Comment: Thanks for the link. So from my understanding, using _id itself it not unsafe. It's only unsafe if you have an insecure system to begin with? (e.g. if there's no authorization and people can access other people's data just by knowing a particular _id)

Answer (score -3):

Yes,is it not recommended to expose your MONGODB_id to the any front end

Comment: Do you have any reasoning or source for that claim?

Comment: A related reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44770035/4861760