# Standard approach for handling MongoDB ObjectId field between entity/DTOs

Tags: mongodb, entity-framework-core

I am learning how to use MongoDB with the new Entity Framework Core provider. The question I have is what is the standard approach to handle the ObjectID in the entities and in the DTOs.

If I just have an Entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And if I return that Entity from a controller to the front end, I get this:

```
{"id":
   {
     "timestamp":1710691969,
      "machine":11536991,
      "pid":-3484,
      "increment":12721767,
      "creationTime":"2024-03-17T16:12:49Z"
   }
}
```

I dont want to send this to the client side for encapsulation and security reasons.

I do not usually return entities to the front end (above was just example), so I would probably have a person DTO which would get sent to the front end. I can have a string property of Id on the DTO and then map Person.Id -> PersonDTO.Id and visa versa. This I have read from various posts and documentation. In this approach, I solved the encapsulation problem, but I am still worried about all the metadata which client side can find out (machine/pid/timestamp/etc).

I also found posts like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62706325/23145140, which mention that after MongoDB v3, there should not be a machine identifier in ObjectID, yet I am using MongoDB 7, and it is still there.

Someone please suggest a way to handle this securely.